# freeRTOS: question about the behavior of API "vTaskPrioritySet"

Tags: embedded, embedded-linux, freertos, rtos

In API `vTaskPrioritySet`:

```
#if ( configUSE_MUTEXES == 1 )
                {
                    /* Only change the priority being used if the task is not
                    currently using an inherited priority. */
                    if( pxTCB->uxBasePriority == pxTCB->uxPriority )
                    {
                        pxTCB->uxPriority = uxNewPriority;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mtCOVERAGE_TEST_MARKER();
                    }

                    /* The base priority gets set whatever. */
                    pxTCB->uxBasePriority = uxNewPriority;
                }
#else
......
```

I noticed that once `priority inheritance` occurs, uxPriority will not be set. My question is: **If the priority set by `vTaskPrioritySet` is higher than the inherited priority, why not use the higher one?**

like this:

```
if( pxTCB->uxBasePriority == pxTCB->uxPriority || uxNewPriority > pxTCB->uxPriority )
{
    pxTCB->uxPriority = uxNewPriority;
}
```

Otherwise, the priority set by `vTaskPrioritySet` will not take effect until the `disinheritance` occurs.

Comment: I think it would break the priority inheritance system and scheduling.